# Error when trying to connect to PnP online in PowerShell post update

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have been developing for SharePoint for awhile now and am familiar with troubleshooting PowerShell, however I cannot resolve this error for the life of me. After updating PnP to the latest version, Connect-PnPOnline no longer functions and results in the following error.

[image: Screenshot of terminal]

As you'd expect, I restored PnP to an older version, that being 3.25.2009.1, while this fixed my issue for the afternoon it has once again returned.. occurring in all versions of PnP. I am unable to do any work until this is resolved.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: What parameters you use for `Connect-SPOService`? Also, are you using this in scripts or for interactive scripting?

Comment: It's being used in a script, I'm using parameters for PnPOnline, those being Url and Credentials

Comment: I test 3.26.2010.0 and 3.28.2012.0, did not reproduce your issue.

Comment: Github has a similar issue:https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/issues/436

Answer (score 1):

Powershel PnP made new registration in Azure AD, which should be approved by global admin before you can use PnP. Got to Azure AD portal, then app registration and search for your app registration
[image]